# Cannot change date time permanently on CentOS 7.3(1611)

Tags: centos

I have CentOS7(1611) on cloud server(provided by Tencent in China), and tried to change time via `date`, `timedatectl`. Time is changed, but the time changed automatically to "real current time" soon(sometimes it reset only about 1 mins after I changed the time). I turned off NTP and chronyd. BTW, ONLY I can access the server, nobody else can change time.

How to check this problem? Or is there any solution to change time permanently?

```
[user@VM_227_172_centos bin]$ systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service - NTP client/server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/chronyd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
[user@VM_227_172_centos bin]$ timedatectl 
      Local time: Thu 2017-08-03 19:33:12 CST
  Universal time: Thu 2017-08-03 11:33:12 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2017-08-03 13:31:19
       Time zone: Asia/Shanghai (CST, +0800)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
[user@VM_227_172_centos bin]$ timedatectl set-time "23:23:21"
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-time ===
Authentication is required to set the system time.
Authenticating as: root
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to set time: Access denied
[user@VM_227_172_centos bin]$ timedatectl set-time "23:23:21"
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-time ===
Authentication is required to set the system time.
Authenticating as: root
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
[user@VM_227_172_centos bin]$ timedatectl 
      Local time: Thu 2017-08-03 23:23:25 CST
  Universal time: Thu 2017-08-03 15:23:25 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2017-08-03 15:23:26
       Time zone: Asia/Shanghai (CST, +0800)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
[user@VM_227_172_centos bin]$ timedatectl 
      Local time: Thu 2017-08-03 23:26:31 CST
  Universal time: Thu 2017-08-03 15:26:31 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2017-08-03 15:26:32
       Time zone: Asia/Shanghai (CST, +0800)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
[user@VM_227_172_centos bin]$ timedatectl 
      Local time: Thu 2017-08-03 19:52:53 CST
  Universal time: Thu 2017-08-03 11:52:53 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2017-08-03 15:42:18
       Time zone: Asia/Shanghai (CST, +0800)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

Please let me know if any info missed.

Answer (score 0):

I used this commands to change timezone for my vicidial server with CentOS 7 :

```
# rm /etc/localtime
rm: remove regular file `/etc/localtime'? y
# ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome localtime
# date
```

and you will see that it is changed.